# php contact form with some additional features...?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

Im looking for a free php contact form script that has these features:

- Captcha or any other working spam protection
- Dropdown boxes for reason of contact (e.g. "Im contacting you because: Bugs/Suggestions/Business")

I know that there are many of these scripts out there, but ive only come across two of them, but not working, mainly because they are outdated.

So who here could link me to a good working one with these features? I shall give this star a plus.

Comment: A form like this is pretty straightforward to build yourself; For the Captcha, try http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Comment: Im unfortunately not very experienced with php. Otherwise I would.

Comment: I assume this is an email-based contact form then?

Comment: building the form itself is mostly HTML and JavaScript work. The captcha I posted is simple to use and provides many examples. Also, you won't be doing much more custom PHP coding than you would if you were using a pre-made contact form

Comment: It is a email-based contact form yes. And SimpleCoder, as you can understand, Im looking for the quick solution. Dont have any time right now to play around with html/javascript, so im hoping that their is a ready script out there that I could just quickly edit and put online. Time is of the essence :P

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure how this question is program-related if you don´t really know php and don´t have the time to play around with html and javascript.

The only copy/paste solutions are (free?) from processors [like this one](http://www.emailmeform.com/). There are probably many more.

Comment: Thank you for nothing. All I was asking for is some assistance to find a script so that I dont need to do much work on it myself. Of course I will end up doing some styling and additional basic programming, but prefer to not do anything major. Thats why I came to Stackoverflow as it has its reputation to have users that can direct one to good scripts and assist on desperate script questions.

Comment: @Petra, Why *thank you for nothing*? The link in my answer seems to fit what you are looking for, you can even get the php source code to process your form in the paid version, but that's not even necessary to just generate and process forms.